# why ? Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$nik

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

please help I have a problem when displaying data,

```
//Model
public function ambiluser()
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('biodata');
    $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
    $sec_qry=$this->db->get();
    return $result=$sec_qry->result();
}
```

View

```
foreach ($user as $row) 
 <td><?php echo $row->nik; ?></td>
```

Comment: Where you are using `stdClass::$nik`?

Comment: this foreach ($user as $row) 
 <td><?php echo $row->nik; ?></td>

Comment: I think column `nik` does not exists

Comment: I think @DanishAli is right. @Lutfiy, are you sure `$row` is the correct object? Or perhaps you forgot to declare `nik` in that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should check if the query returned any results! Like this:

```
if($sec_qry->num_rows() > 0){
    return $sec_qry->result();
}
return false;
```

And second in your view:

```
<?php if( $user && !empty($user) ) :?>
    <?php foreach( $user as $row ) :?>
        <td><?=$row->nik;?></td>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```